# Unable to use Phpmyadmin, settings prompt gives an error while installing

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just finished installing Phpmyadmin on my old mac book, everything seems to be working fine apart from Phpmyadmin. I've configured Apache server with the required settings but still no luck.

While installing Phpmyadmin from software center something went wrong when, it prompted for some settings but it din't go further and stopped with an error code(started with 1000.. something), probably the issue lies in the settings config.

Should I reinstall and see if it goes through the settings prompt or do you recommend any other alternative tool ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good that you mentioned about the error you got while installing phpmyadmin. While installing, the settings window was not able to save required configs for some reason(probably permission issues) run the below code to invoke the phphmyadmin from the terminal settings page and follow the instructions.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm! Thanks again Srinivas :)